# Ins on motor wiring diagram

Tags: induction-motor

I'm trying to connect a 220 single phase motor, the wiring diagram is on a sticker on the motor. However, I'm not sure what the Brown wire is supposed to be connected to, I think it says "Ins" which I'm interpreting as insulation, therefore I should just insulate the wire.

Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The brown wire is not connected to anything, but it must be insulated.

Comment: Thanks, I got a hold of the manufacturer and confirmed that the Brn wire has to be insulated.